# How to write it formally? Convergence of an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, formal-proofs

I know that the following sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2n}} e^{-\sqrt{n}}$$ converges because it's basically looking at $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-\sqrt{n}} \sim \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} e^{-\sqrt{x}} dx = \frac{2}{e},$$ which is convergent. But how can I make this reasoning more formal?

Comment: You don't need the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2n}}$ to get convergence, so you can ignore it. The sum of the exponential is easy to prove converges, e.g. since $\exp\sqrt n$ grows faster than $n^2$.

Comment: Apply the inequality $$(2n+1)^{-1/2}e^{-n^{1/2}}\le n^{-1/2}e^{-n^{1/2}}\le \int\limits_{n-1}^nx^{-1/2}e^{-x^{1/2}}\,dx $$ Then sum up from $2$ to $\infty.$

Comment: Use the following inequalities: 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2n}} e^{-\sqrt{n}}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-\sqrt{n}} < \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} e^{-\sqrt{x}} dx=2.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your results as given you could use [the limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test). Observe that
$$
 \frac{\left(\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2n}} e^{-\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\left(\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-\sqrt{n}}\right)} 
= \sqrt{ \frac{n}{1+2n} } \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \in (0,\infty)
$$
Since you know that the simpler sum converges, you have the convergence of the desired sum.

Comment: I didn't know about this test. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would rather apply the comparison test as $(2n+1)^{-1/2}\le n^{-1/2}.$ The limit comparison test is useful if the expressions cannot be compared easily but the asymptotic behaviour of their ratio can be determined.

Comment: Perhaps in general. I'm simply seeing the information given to me by the OP. With this information, finishing a proof via LCT is a one-liner. Is it the fastest way they could've done it overall? Perhaps not. But it is probably the fastest that they could do it with the work they've already done.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{1+2n}}\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{n}}\le e^{-1}+\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}\ dx=\frac{3}{e} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{1+2n}}&<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{2n}} \\
&\sim\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{n}}\end{align*}$$
$e^{-\sqrt n}/\sqrt{n}$ is continuous and monotone decreasing on $n\in[1,\infty)$, hence by the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence),
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-\sqrt n}}{\sqrt{n}}\sim\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x}\ dx}_{2/e}$$
the improper integral is finite and the series converges.